# jQuery- e.target || e.srcElement not working on class

Tags: php, jquery, html, search

I have an instant search in which the result goes in "*instant-search*" div. There is another div "*search-radio*" in which I have kept the option to select search category.

I have set a document click event that removes the result, but the result also disappears when clicking in "*instant-search*" div.

I have set some **e.target || e.srcElement** event to prevent result from disappearing on "*instant-search*" div click.

This works perfectly in Firefox, but it doesn't work in any other browser.

**My complete jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#search-radio').css('display', 'block');
 $('#search-input').keyup(function()
    {
     var searchIn = $("input:radio:checked").val();
     var keyword=$(this).val();
     $.get('../search/instant-search.php', {keyword: keyword, searchIn:searchIn}, function(data)
        {
        $('#instant-search').html(data);
         });
         $('#search-result').fadeIn(250);
     });

  $('#search-input').attr('autocomplete','off');
  $('#search-input').attr('placeholder','Search');

  $('#search-input').mouseenter(function(){$('#search-result').fadeIn(250);});
  $('#search-input').mouseleave(function(){$('#search-result').fadeOut(250);});

  $('#search-result').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function()
  { 
      $('#search-result').stop();

      $(document).on('click', function(e) 
       {
        if(
           ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) != 'instant-search') 
        && ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) != 'search-input') 
        && ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) != 'search-result')
        && ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) != 'search-radio') 
        && ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) !='instant-search-container') 
        && ((e.target || e.srcElement).hasclass != 'instant-search') 
        && ((e.target.id || e.srcElement.id) !='check-all')) 
          {
          $('#search-result').fadeOut(250);
          }
       });

   });

});
```

**MY HTML Code:**

```
    <div id="search-wrapper">
<form action="" method="get" id="search-form" >
<div id="search">
<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50"  id="search-input"  />
</div><!--end of search-->

<div id="search-result">
<div id="instant-search"></div><!--end of instant-search-->
<div id="search-radio">
<p>Search In:</p>
  <ul>
      <li><label><input name="search" type="radio" value="all" checked="checked" id="check-all" >All</label></li>
      <li><label><input name="search" type="radio" value="Category2" >Category2</label></li>
      <li><label><input name="search" type="radio" value="Category3" >Category3</label></li>
      <li><label><input name="search" type="radio" value="Category4" >Category4</label></li>
      <li><label><input name="search" type="radio" value="Category5" >Category5</label></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--end of search-radio-->
</div><!--end of search-result-->
</form>
</div><!--end of search-wrapper-->
```

**Edit:** Please see **e.target || e.srcElement** not working on **ul li** and **radio input** only elsewhere working.

I want this to work on all browsers.

Please see and suggest any possible way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: @Raminson Thanks for proper editing my codes. can you tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: @Blaine Thanks for proper editing my codes again.

Comment: np, and I wish I could help you out, but I'm stumped

Comment: It looks like you are trying to exclude almost all the elements in the search-wrapper div when clicking the document, is it all of them, and if so why not just target them all at once ?

Comment: yes i am trying to exclude all the elements in search-wrapper, how to target all at once including ul li, i know this way only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#search-radio').css('display', 'block');

    $('#search-input').on({
        keyup: function() {
            var searchIn = $("input:radio:checked").val();
            var keyword = this.value;
            $.get('../search/instant-search.php', {
                keyword: keyword,
                searchIn: searchIn
            }, function(data) {
                $('#instant-search').html(data);
            });
            $('#search-result').stop().fadeIn(250);
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('#search-result').stop().fadeIn(250);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('#search-result').stop().fadeOut(250);
        }
    }).attr('autocomplete', 'off').attr('placeholder', 'Search');

    $('#search-result').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $('#search-result').stop();
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        var flag = true;
        $.each($('*','#search-wrapper'), function(i,elm) {
            if (e.target===elm) flag=false;
        });
        if (flag) $('#search-result').fadeOut(250);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljsey/1/)

Comment: You are awesome, now its working perfectly in all browser. also i have one more issue with it. when leaving mouse out of "search-input" area and quickly bringing over to "search-result" area the fadout transection stops in between, can you check it.

Comment: Not sure I see it, but try adding some stops. Edited the code above ? Also be aware that checking a lot of elements on every click on the document is not very efficient, but in most cases it won't be an issue.

Comment: If i name `searchIn` to `search`, why var `search` is then highlighted in green then regular black.

Comment: I really I have no idea? Are you saying that selecting the first radio button "all" makes something highlight in green? Is it the same in all browsers, and is this in the fiddle or on your site with search results and everything ?

Comment: No its in this line gets highlighted to green `var searchIn = $("input:radio:checked").val();` like if its some special jquery var now.

Comment: If it's in the code you mean, that's probably because [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) is a built in javascript method, and probably not a good name for a variable.